# OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE doesn't share read?

Tags: c++, windows, file, share, creation

I am creating a video in my app with AVIFileOpen(&pfile, fn, OF_WRITE | OF_CREATE | OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE, NULL); and I can't acces the avi file while it is creating.

What's the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debugged into the function and it is calling CreateFile() with dwShareMode = 0 (exclusive); somewhere along the way it is losing the share mode.  Didn't work with OF_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, either.  I guess it's just a bug.  This was on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Do document what Windows version you tried this on.

Comment: ok thank you, I can avoid that by fir opening the file with read and write sharing with CreateFile...